# NFS server setup: 192.168.1.0/24 vs 192.168.1.*

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nfs

I have my nfs server running on `192.168.1.99` box, and I have my /etc/exports configured using

```
/myshare 192.168.1.*(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

I was able to mount nfs from `192.168.1.50` client box.

However I was unable to mount from `192.168.1.49`! ("mount.nfs mount(2) permission denied" followed by "mount.nfs access denied by server while mounting")

Then I found that I can make connection if I change client's ip to `192.168.1.48`

Finally, I was able to make it work by using `192.168.1.0/24` instead of `192.168.1.*`

Could anybody explain why `192.168.1.0/24` works for `192.168.1.49`, but `192.168.1.*` does not?

```
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
```

... I'm not an administrator, and I have weak understanding of subnets... Ubuntu64, 12.04...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the manpage of `exports(5)`:

```
Machine Name Formats
NFS clients may be specified in a number of ways:

[...]

IP networks
    You  can  also  export  directories  to  all hosts on an IP (sub-) network
    simultaneously. This is done by specifying an IP address and netmask  pair
    as  address/netmask  where  the netmask can be specified in dotted-decimal
    format,  or  as  a  contiguous   mask   length.    For   example,   either
    `/255.255.252.0'  or  `/22'  appended  to  the  network  base IPv4 address
    results in identical subnetworks with 10 bits of host. [...]
    Wildcard characters generally  do  not  work on IP addresses, though they
    may work by accident when reverse DNS lookups fail.

wildcards
    Machine names may contain the wildcard characters * and ?, or may  contain
    character  class lists within [square brackets].  This can be used to make
    the exports file more compact;  for  instance,  *.cs.foo.edu  matches  all
    hosts  in  the domain cs.foo.edu.  As these characters also match the dots
    in a domain name, the given pattern will also match all hosts  within  any
    subdomain of cs.foo.edu.
```

This simply means you're configuring it wrong in the line

```
/myshare 192.168.1.*(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Wildcards can be used in hostnames, for specifying IP networks, you need to use dotted-decimal IP addresses and an optional subnet size. The reverse IP-lookup story above could explain why it worked for a specific address.

Comment: 192.168.1.* worked for 192.168.1.50, nslookup 192.168.1.50 returns  server can't find 50.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN (run on NFS server). Same thing with 192.16.1.49

Comment: Also 192.168.1.* worked for 192.168.1.48

Comment: 'may work by accident' is a strange wording

Comment: You're hitting undefined behaviour by not following documentation. Besides, `nslookup` is not the same as standard libc resolving (e.g. does not use `/etc/hosts`).